# PHP GET link onetime valid

Tags: php, get

How can i transform a link whit GET variables to make it **available one time?**

Example link: http://example.com?id=45&cod=15&idncc=16

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does it mean `available one time`?

Comment: like an "activation link", available one time

Comment: You maybe need to use time boxed tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The link will update a row in a mysql table, and this row must be updated only one time

So, you can add a `tinyint` column named `updated` in your table. Before update the row, check if `updated` is `0`. If it is, then you can update the row and change the `updated` value to `1`. If it isn't, then send an error message.

Comment: Thanks! Good idea! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the back end, check the parameters of the URL passed in.

If the parameter has been accessed before, response with a 404 response code.

Otherwise, serve the request as you see fit.

Comment: The link will update a row in a mysql table, and this row must be updated only one time,